# Decryption of two password using one object?

Tags: python, encryption

I need to decrypt 2 passwords in one class file using one object. Decryption works fine for first password. It is giving garbage value for second password decryption.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

obj = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
a = b'R\xa9\xd2)[\x9a\x99\xd9' #devuser1
print("Encrypt: ",ciphertext)
obj2 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')
print ("Decrypt: ", obj2.decrypt(ciphertext))
print ("Decrypt: ", obj2.decrypt(a))
```

It is working fine if I use 2 different object for decryption.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

obj = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
a = b'R\xa9\xd2)[\x9a\x99\xd9' #devuser1
print("Encrypt: ",ciphertext)
obj2 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')
obj3 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')
print ("Decrypt: ", obj2.decrypt(ciphertext))
print ("Decrypt: ", obj3.decrypt(a))
```

Is there anyway we can decrypt using only `obj2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You're using [CFB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_(CFB)), which requires state and makes `obj.encrypt` and `obj.decrypt` not pure functions:

```
In [1]: from Crypto.Cipher import AES

In [2]: obj = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')

In [3]: obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
Out[3]: b'R\xa9\xd2)[\x9a\x99'

In [4]: obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
Out[4]: b'\x8c)l\xcc\t<\x82'

In [5]: obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
Out[5]: b'\xae\xea)dv6\x82'

In [6]: obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
Out[6]: b'\xe9\xd5\xc5kH+\x05'

In [7]: obj.encrypt(b'devuser')
Out[7]: b'\xf3\x8b\xaf\xe7\xac\xca*'
```

CFB mode may not be the best mode for your particular application since it allows only part of your plaintext to be corrupted by an attacker, leaving the rest intact:

```
In [1]: from Crypto.Cipher import AES

In [2]: aes1 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')

In [3]: aes2 = AES.new(b'This is a key123', AES.MODE_CFB, b'This is a key123')

In [4]: plaintext = b'0123456789' * 20

In [5]: plaintext
Out[5]: b'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'

In [6]: ciphertext = aes1.encrypt(plaintext)

In [7]: corrupted = ciphertext[:80] + b'?' * 20 + ciphertext[120:]

In [8]: corrupted_plaintext = aes2.decrypt(corrupted)

In [9]: corrupted_plaintext
Out[9]: b'01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
890123456789\x11\xfe\x12z\x04[\xe3N\x8b)a\x87gF\xc4XIIII\xe4L:?\xe2.\x04cx\xa3
\xd2\xf6r>W\x066789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
```

Answer (score 0):

The cipher object is stateful, which means that you cannot reuse an object for encrypting or decrypting other data with the same key.